# In tableview i have 4 static cells. How do i make row height automatically calculated to fit the label inside and one manually

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

So i have four sections and one cell in each one of the sections in my static tableview. One of them is displaying a picture and for that one i manually calculate the ration and multiply it by the width and that way i get the correct height. I do that using the "heightForRowAtIndexPath".

I also have three other cells and each one has a label in it. The labels content is different each time since i'm segueing to it from a different cell so sometimes the cell should be big enough for 1 row of text and sometimes for more. How do i calculate/set that to happen automatically?

Also in my storyboard i have the constrains for the label set to be 8 point away from the right left and top, thats all the constrains that are on the label. I already tried setting the tableView.rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimensions but that doesn't do anything. The rows just stay at the same height as they were set in the "heightForRowAtIndexPath" or the same as in the storyboard if that function is not implemented. Been trying to solve that for probably more then an hour now and still cant figure it out. Thanks for the help. Also i'm doing all of this in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` it will also override any value for the table view's `rowHeight`. So, in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, and do the same in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` too.

As long as your cell has a solid Auto Layout configuration, that's all it takes to make auto-sizing cells work.

Comment: I tried that, and it didnt work.
and I also set the estimatedRowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimensions and when a label is the 2 rows high the cell stay at the same height. How should i have my constrains in the storyboard setup? Is it possible that the problem is that i have a static not dynamic tableView?

Comment: This my function now and it still doesnt work.

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section{
        case 0:
            if image != nil {
                return imageCell.bounds.size.width * CGFloat(imageRatio!)
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        default:
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }

Comment: Does the label have `numberOfLines` set to 0 so that it can resize?

Comment: Yes it does, when there is too much text in the label the second raw is then just partially visible and the 3rd one is way below the visible field since the row is too small.

Comment: You might need to post your project somewhere; I suspect there's something else at play here.

Comment: Yeah im thinking the same thing. Would you mind checking it for me if thats not a problem? If the problem is not visible in a sensible period of time you can just drop it. Thnks

Comment: Sure; put the project on GitHub or Dropbox.

Comment: Thank you. You are a lifesaver, i will do that now. Give me a second

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/telnvalwx1ftpqp/mashTag.zip?dl=0 Here is the link. The problem is accuring in the "DetailTableViewController" and all the cells in it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your problem is that you haven't specified a full set of Auto Layout constraints: you need to add constraint for the bottom as well. I just tried it here, and once top, bottom, left and right constraints have been set for your labels, automatic dimensions works as above.

Comment: I would add, though, that your labels aren't doing anything much – you could use the built in table view cell types and get this behaviour automatically. (Although you need to double-check the `numberOfLines` property is set to 0.

Comment: Thanks you, i cant believe i didnt try that before. I had it set that way and had something else set wrong so thinking this was the problem i removed the bottom constraint and never changed it back. Thank you very much again. Also, love your hacking with swift series, great work. :)

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed – and I'm glad you're enjoying my tutorials :)  Don't forget to mark my answer as correct so others can benefit too.